# Create instance of a dialog and call it from the mainwindow

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, qt

I'm coming from Qt where i had a dialog class and used it like this to open the dialog from the mainwindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    Dialog *x = new Dialog();
    x->show();}
```

Now i want to do the same using WPF.
How do i create a dialog as a class and how to use it?

Comment: What type of dialog you want?

Comment: A simple dialog with a textbox to input a value and a Ok/Cancel button.

Comment: Are you wanting to show a `CommonDialog` a simple `MessageBox` or a custom window?

Comment: I want a simple custom window to get the idea.

Comment: There is a `ShowDialog` method on the window class so you add a new window to your solution, design as necessary, and then call `ShowDialog`. Getting the result back gets a bit tricker.

Comment: I see. But if i want  to teste if the user pressed the Ok or Cancel button in the dialog, to decide how to use the value entered in the textbox, i gess i will have to go for the "a bit tricker" approach.

Comment: Not tricky so much as more verbose and starts getting into why MVVM is a popular pattern for WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `Window` to use as your input dialog:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyInputDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyInputDialog"
        Height="130"
        Width="300">
    <DockPanel Margin="15">
        <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                     Margin="5"
                     Rows="1"
                     >
            <Button Content="Ok"
                    x:Name="bOk"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Click="bOk_Click"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    />
            <Button Content="Cancel"
                    x:Name="bCancel"
                    IsCancel="True"
                    Click="bCancel_Click"   
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    />
        </UniformGrid>        

        <DockPanel Margin="5" >
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Text="Input a value:"
                        />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbResult"/>

        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MyInputDialog.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MyInputDialog : Window
{
    public MyInputDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void bCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

Then in the main `Window` show `MyInputDialog` modally with `ShowDialog` and inspect the value of the `TextBox`

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new MyInputDialog();
        if(dialog.ShowDialog()== true)
        {
            var input = dialog.tbResult.Text;
        }
    }
```